# How to apply OpenLayers Stymbolizer Contexts on the Fly?

Tags: openlayers

For the reasons detailed in [How to keep OpenLayers.StyleMap and OpenLayers.SelectFeature from conflicting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049755/how-to-keep-openlayers-stylemap-and-openlayers-selectfeature-from-conflicting), I have some style code that looks like:

```
myStyle.Events = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
myStyle.Events.extendDefault = true;
myStyle.Events.maxScaleDenominator = 200000000;
myStyle.Events.graphicWidth = 36;
myStyle.Events.graphicHeight = 36;
myStyle.Events.graphicOpacity = 0.75;
myStyle.Events.externalGraphic = "/img/icons/${icon}.png";
myStyle.Events.label = "${count}";
myStyle.Events.labelOutlineWidth = 1;
myStyle.Events.labelOutlineColor = "#000";
myStyle.Events.fontColor = "#000";
myStyle.Events.fontOpacity = 8.0;
myStyle.Events.fontSize = "11px";
myStyle.Events.labelYOffset = 3;

myStyle.Events.context = {
  icon: function(feature) {
    var iconMap,
        iconPath,
        type = "single";

    iconMap = {
      ...
    }

    if(feature.attributes.count) {
      type = "clustered";
    }

    return iconMap[feature.attributes.name][type];
  },
  count: function(feature) {
    var labelText = "";

    if(feature.attributes.count) {
      labelText = feature.attributes.count;
    }

    return labelText;
  }
};
```

How can I correctly apply that context on the fly like that? I can't do the typical OpenLayers.Style({}, {context: context}); syntax here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must apply the `context` property to an `OpenLayers.Style` instance, like this:

```
var style = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);
style.pointRadius = "${radius}";
style.fillColor = '${colorFunction}';

var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style(style, {
    context: {
        colorFunction: function(feature) {
            return colors[feature.attributes.temp];
        }
    }
});
```

I recommend you the [OpenLayers Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/openlayers-create-gis-web-applications-cookbook/book) (theme 7 Styling) or look at source code examples http://acanimal.github.io/Openlayers-Cookbook/ (chapter 7 - Improving style using StyleMap and feature's attributes replacement )

Cheers.